# Fill cell color in if two percentage nearly same

Tags: excel

Hi as you can see blow the number 3 has a fill color in green

I have two percentage cells and I would like the number cell to be filled if the two percentage cells are same or there’s about 5% difference etc

Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: same or there about's 5% difference etc

Comment: Ok so just to confirm, you want the cell with the 3 in it to be green if the difference between the two percentages is within 5% absolute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is as shown ...

[image: Data]

... you can put a conditional format in cell **B1** with a rule set behind **Use a formula to determine which cells to format** ...

```
=ABS((C1/E1)-1) <= 0.05
```

Just watch your absolute references if you want to fill down (i.e. my image shows absolute but my formula directly above shows relative).

It worked for me.